# Laravel login and logout with two roles

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have installed adminlte on laravel and it's builtin login functionality works fine. I have two roles in users table. Admin and Customer. Admin has to login through admin panel screen.its works ok. Customer has to login through front end website by login screen.
Question is:

When I login customer through front end website , it logins and I redirect him/her to some front page. When I open admin panel login screen , it redirects to admin dashboard as we already login..but it must not go to admin dashboard,It must remains on admin login page. Any solution for that. How to tackle that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use middleware on the admin routes to check if the user is an admin user, something like the below would work if you have an `is_admin` flag on your user model:

```
class IsAdminMiddleware
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if (Auth::guest()) {
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }

            if (!$request->user()->is_admin) {
                abort(403, 'Not Authorised');
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK ..let me do this..Thank you for your response, I will comment again if some problem occurs or if something is not getting by me.